# Profile picture is no longer greyed out if not on display

Tags: bug, jobs, profile-page, profile-picture

I just saw the new Careers profile editor design, and noticed that my Gravatar was no longer greyed out as it was before, since I opted not to display it.

So I thought that the image now *was* perhaps being displayed, though hovering over the image no longer reveals an "Edit" icon, so I couldn't easily check this setting.

I discovered that hovering over my name reveals a large blue area (with name, location, URL, etc.) indicating that these values are editable, but this area does not stretch to include the image.  Nevertheless, the "display image" option is now included in there.

So, it would be nice if the image was greyed out again in the profile editor, and hovering over it also revealed the edit functionality.

Comment: What's the purpose of showing a placeholder image there? If you've told us that you don't want to display your avatar, we interpret that to mean you don't want an image representing you. (I know it's different than what we used to do – trying to understand if there's some problem you're trying to solve, or if you just noticed it was different. ;) )

Comment: The problem to solve is the same as before — being able to easily determine whether my profile picture is visible on my careers profile. Previously, it wasn't so much a "placeholder image", but rather a greyed-out version of my actual profile image which — exactly like greyed-out "Top 10%" tags — made it clear that my profile picture was not visible to employers. But yeah, I guess also hiding the image entirely if "Display Gravatar" is unchecked may be a potential solution.